# Assigning values to array of 'Combo Boxes' in a 'Group Box' using for each loop in c#

Tags: combobox, foreach, c#-3.0

I have 10 comboBox in a groupBox
for I just want to display a calculated value in respective comboBox like this say if I set a varible double i=08.00; then on button click cmboBox should display values like this

```
CB1-08.00
CB2-09.50
CB3-10.00
CB4-10.50
CB5-11.00
CB6-11.50
```

.... and so on upto CB10 But I am getting output like this
[image]

And Code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double i=08.00;
        foreach (var comboBox in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
        {
            comboBox.Text = i.ToString("00.00");
            i = i + 0.5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: step through in the debugger....

Comment: The order in which you get the Controls out of the Controls Collection is more or less random. Add  an .orderby(x=> x.Name) to get them in a sorted order when they are named like you say.

Comment: @Ralf I think what you are saying is the reason for wrong output, can you please where to use the piece of code you mentioned in your suggestion

Comment: foreach (var comboBox in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name))

Comment: @Ralf BEAUTIFUL Thank you for this small code but BIG USE

Comment: The problem with order by name is that, if your number of combo boxes goes above 10, then the order will not be numericaly sorted, for example CB11, will be sorted before CB2.

Answer (score 3):

Your combobox order is different in the collection so it inserts the numbers randomly. May be you can name your combobox for instance like cmb1,cmb2,cmb3 etc. and if you update your code it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Your controls in the `Controls` collection are not sorted by their appearance on the form. You will need to find a way to sort them if you need different values in each based on their position.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loop doesn't give the collection in the order you wanted. The way to go forward is to give a tag id to each combo box, then you can use that to assign a value to them them.

So your first combo box will start with tag id 0, and the last one will have 8,

```
        double val = 08.00;
        for (int i = 0; i < groupBox1.Controls.Count; ++i)
        {
            var combobox = groupBox1.Controls[i] as ComboBox;
            int tag = int.Parse(combobox.Tag.ToString());
            double value = val + (0.5 * tag);
            combobox.Text = value.ToString("00.00");
        }
```

Make sure you tag the cobbo box in the order you wanted them.